# How to ignore ld warning about missing i386 architecture for device-only framework

Tags: ios, ld, ios-frameworks

My app employes an external device (hardware accessory).  I'm using a framework provided by the hardware supplier, but this only runs on the device (they do no support running in the simulator).  Because of this, I'm getting the following warning when I compile:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ...xxx.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
...xxx.a (2 slices)
```

Is there any way to tune my project configuration so that I no longer get this error when building for the simulator?  I know it's a cosmetic issue, but I'd rather have my build log clean when I have no (real) problems in my code.

Comment: How did you add the lib ? Using the "Library Search Paths" ? If so you could add the library fo devices only.

Comment: @Xval: yes, it's added using library search paths, but I don't see how to specify it should be used for devices only; do you mean I should set up different build schemes?

Answer (score 0):

In the project setting, it's possible to add different libraries according to the current configuration and/or the os. Thus you can add your library only if your building for a real an iOS SDK (and not for the iOS simulator SDK).

[image]